# How to send a string with & in it as a querystring value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, query-string

How can i send a string with a & in it (Ex : google & facebook) as the querystring value ? Now

```
var strUrl="ajaxpage.aspx?subject=my subject line &cmnt=google & facebook";
strUrl = encodeURI(strUrl);

$.ajax({ url: strUrl, success: function (data) {
     alert(data)
     }
 });
```

Now when i read query string "cmnt", I am getting only "google" because it breaks the &

What is the workaround for this ? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is: Use [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) on data strings before sticking them in query strings.

The slightly longer answer is: You're using jQuery. It will fix this for you if you let it. Let the URL be just the URL to the main resource, then pass any data you want in the query string using the `data` property of the object you pass to the ajax method.

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: "ajaxpage.aspx", 
    data: { 
        subject: "my subject line",
        cmnt: "google & facebook"
    },
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data)
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 5):

You will need to encode that character or the entire url

---

`&` would be encoded as `%26`

```
var strUrl="ajaxpage.aspx?subject=my subject line &cmnt=google %26 facebook";
```

---

or call `encodeURIComponent()`

```
var strUrl = "ajaxpage.aspx" 
    + "?subject=" + encodeURIComponent("my subject line")
    + "&cmnt=" + encodeURIComponent("google & facebook");
```

Comment: Umm. When you encodeURIComponent you have to do it on a *component* of a URI, not the whole query string. With that example it will encode **all** the `&` and `=` so the query string will just be one big string and have no key/value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

Try using <strike>`escape`</strike>[(see why)](http://xkr.us/articles/javascript/encode-compare/) `encodeURIComponent` on 'google & facebook' and append to query string.

But I would recommend @Quentin's jQuery fix!

Comment: Don't use escape. Never use escape. It has been deprecated with good reason.

Comment: @Quentin: Yes, you're right. There are caveats, so I shouldn't be posting it for general consumption like I did.

Answer (score 0):

You can URL encode it as %26. Will that work for what you need to do?